# How to parse a log file in Java?

Tags: java, parsing, logfile, logparser

I have a file that has this two rows of data.

```
Jan 1 22:54:17 drop   %LOGSOURCE% >eth1 rule: 7; rule_uid: {C1336766-9489-  4049-9817-50584D83A245}; src: 70.77.116.190; dst: %DSTIP%; proto: tcp; product: VPN-1 & FireWall-1; service: 445; s_port: 2612;
Jan 1 23:02:56 accept %LOGSOURCE% >eth1 inzone: External; outzone: Local; rule: 3; rule_uid: {723F81EF-75C9-4CBB-8913-0EBB3686E0F7}; service_id: icmp-proto; ICMP: Echo Request; src: 24.188.22.101; dst: %DSTIP%; proto: icmp; ICMP Type: 8; ICMP Code: 0; product: VPN-1 & FireWall-1;
```

May I really know what's the code to parse them into different columns? One problem is

```
eth1 rule:7;
eth1 inzone: External; outzone: Local;
```

I want to let them fall under the same column. I really need some desperate help as I have no knowledge of programming and I'm tasked to do this ><

Comment: Please start doing some code by yourself , then if you got stucked with some exact issue, then someone will be able to  help you. Refer this link for [asking proper questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I don't even know what are the basic steps to code.. 0 percent knowledge of java but i'll try..

Comment: Then you should look for some tutorial or post it in freelancer. We cannot expect people to do coding from scratch for you. This site is just for helping in issue.

Comment: I'll go a bit out of topic, but if you have 0 programming knowledge and have been tasked to write code, maybe you have a bigger problem in your organization and should seek to raise it....

Answer (score 1):

You'd probably start with Java's split function for strings:

[Oracle Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))

[Look at example 3](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~hasti/cs302/examples/Parsing/parseString.html)

I assume you could lump your first column as everything from the start to '>' after %LOGSOURCE%.  I'm also guessing there are other columns that would be lumped together and that in the end you'd only expect a certain amount of columns per row.

You could use code like this:

```
//a line of the log can be split on '>' and ';' for the other columns of interest
//logLine is a line off the your log, I'm assuming it's a string object
string[] splitLine = logLine.split("[>;]+");
//I'm pretending there are 7 columns, for simplicity sake I'm using an ArrayList
// of string arrays (ArraList<string[]>) that would get declared
//above all this called logList
string[] logEntry = new string[7];
//Save the time stamp of the log entry by iterating through splitLine
for(int counter1 = 0; counter1 < splitLine.length; counter1++)
{
   //Timestamp column
   if(counter1 == 0)
      logEntry[0] = splitLine[counter1];

   //First column
   if(counter1 == 1)
      logEntry[1] = splitLine[counter1];
   //Logic to determine what needs to get appended to second column, 
   //could be many if statements
   if(...)
      logEntry[1] += splitLine[counter1];

   //Logic to determine what starts third column
   if(...)
      logEntry[2] = splitLine[counter1];
   //Logic to determine what needs to get appended to third column,
   //could be many if statements
   if(...)
      logEntry[2] += splitLine[counter1];
   //And so on... till you fill all your columns up or as much as you want
}
//Add your columned log to your list for use after you've parsed up the file
logList.add(logEntry);
```

You'd probably stick all this logic in a for loop that continually grabs a line off your log into the logLine string used at the top of the code sample.  It's not the most efficient way, but it's pretty straightforward.  Hopefully this gives you a start to approaching your problem.